# Is there a way to cheat javascript games (like Unicoin mining) where rapid clicking is required?

Tags: xorg, javascript

I saw that there's a new currency on the site today for higher privileges called Unicoin. You can mine them by clicking quickly.

I was wondering if there's any Ubuntu wizardry that could speed up the process of mining these coins (and by extension to prove that Ubuntu is better than Windows).

Any help appreciated. Index finger is getting tired.

Comment: Is it possible to edit the question to be more general. I know it was fun on 1st April (and was very Meta to be posted on Main)... But essentially, it is about using something on Ubuntu... It is about how to make my computer perform automatic mouse-clicks with least amount of manual intervention... And **it is** very useful because I have earlier found reasons for doing it. In its present form, after a certain period of time people would hardly know what was Unicoin mining all about. Food for thought because it attracted a close-vote as off-topic!

Comment: Is this a secondary April Fools joke, extending/subclassing the Unicoin April Fools joke? Or maybe you're just interested in Unicoin-mining hacks regardless (just like I had fun mining Unicoins regardless)? Or maybe Unicoin mining just became a vehicle for a(n implied) general question about mouse-clicking hacks?

Comment: @J0e3gan: I have [previously encountered the requirement for automatic mouse-clicking](http://askubuntu.com/a/246551/114818) where I used `xdotool` to do the job... Not to mention, this wasn't the only instance. I once downloaded a similar tool for Windows because I had to perform some action which required me to click mouse at the same position numerous number of times.. So, it's not a joke from my side.. I've found its uses a fair number of times to appreciate the value of this question.. :-)

Comment: I think a "browser game" is more appropriate than "Javascript game". A few years ago, I used Javascript to aid in/automate some parts of a browser game. While an autoclicker works, it is still more reliable to use scripting because you can show feedback with aggregated details.

Comment: @J0e3gan: I just recalled the purpose it was useful for me on Windows... One of the applications had crashed and it popped hundreds/thousands of dialog boxes (and was continuously generating them at a very fast pace) and I had to click on the Okay/Cancel button on all of those boxes to get rid of the situation... It was one of the hilarious moments in my computing life.. :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following method is cross-platform, it works also for other SE sites. <sub>Oh, and it is also cross-platform in the sense that it works for other operating systems.</sub>

Based on [this meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227311/you-have-75-unicoins#comment744975_227311) comment, I have created the following script that automatically starts mining every 15 seconds, from the moment of invocation:

> `(function(fn){setInterval(fn,15e3);fn()})(function() { $.get("/unicoin/rock").done(function(obj) { console.log("Mining: ", obj); var key = obj.rock; $.post(["/unicoin/mine?rock=" + key], {fkey: StackExchange.options.user.fkey}); }); });`

As this is a script, you should execute it on the SE domain where you wish to accelerate your mining. In Firefox, you can open the Console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>. In Chromium, simply press F12. Paste it and gain coins! To stop it, simply refresh (or close) the page.

Note: you should not execute this multiple times. That would make the Unicoins economy collapse and therefore measures have been taken such that you cannot get coins in that case.

Comment: Now a codegolf answer: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25200/11259

Comment: @DigitalTrauma No account on codegolf, but you can surely drop some `;` and a space. The `key` variable (`k`) is also used only once, so that could be dropped too. The whole `(function(fn){...;fn()})(FOO);` can be replaced by `setInterval(FOO,2e4)` to safe even more space (functional difference: it will not immediately mine a coin, but start after 20 seconds).

Comment: Thanks I golfed it down quite a bit with your suggestions!  Guess I'll have to (re)learn JS one of these days

Comment: You should have checked for the User-Agent first, and make sure it's Ubuntu. And make the script Ubuntu-specific! That's some "fanboyism" right here!

Comment: @Dan The time has already done the work, it does not work for browsers that do not run Ubuntu!

Answer (score 20):

If you want to give your finger a rest you can use the following to automatically send multiple (10,000 in this case) clicks to the current cursor location.

```
xdotool click --repeat 10000 --delay 10 1
```

I suggest you open a terminal first put the command in (leave focus with the terminal) and then move the mouse over the mining screen before pressing return so that the clicks end up in the correct place.

As soon as one boulder is mined, move your mouse over to the next one. Don't leave the game area until the command has finished running unless you want to unleash chaos on your system.

---

**Post April-fools update:** This will also be handy in instances where you can't hack around the browser with javascript. There are a few games out there —and not just in browsers— that rely on quick clicking where this sort of workaround can help.

Comment: Downvote: This is misleading as it will generate less revenue than the cost of a mouse button, unless you use a high resilient and expensive gaming mouse or a touch screen.

Comment: This has attracted a flag so for clarity I should add that this doesn't actually click your mouse buttons or level any extra wear on it. It just sends X events that look like mouse clicks. Blimey people.

Comment: Modern mouses have haptic feedback enabled by default. When you send an X event the left button will press itself to give you feedback. This will wear cheap mouses quickly. Some motherboards have a BIOS option to disable it, but it's far from common.

Comment: Huh... `--delay 10` all but locks up Firefox on my old computer; `--delay 20` works OK, though. Clearly, I need better hardware for any serious mining.

Comment: @JavierRivera your mouse vibrates?

Comment: @JavierRivera I think you are neglecting the increase in the value of unicoins that will surely happen once the initial mining period ends

Answer (score 3):

There is `xautoclick` available and I have tested on 12.04.

1. Download the .deb and install from http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/getdeb_apps/quantal/apps/getdeb/xautoclick
2. Adjust the settings to something like this:

   [image]
3. Click start, and move the mouse over to the mining field before it starts.

Answer (score 2):

There is a JS wizzardy to do this. Check the script I wrote.
Just paste this in your console and click enter. Do not forget to open mining game.

```
var exploit = {
    lastTime : 0,
    totalNum: 0
};

$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
    var a = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
    var id = a.rock;
    var sender = settings.url;

    if (sender.indexOf("icoin/rock?") !== -1){
        var currentTime = parseInt( new Date().getTime() / 1000 );
        if (currentTime - exploit.lastTime > 11){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/unicoin/mine?rock=" + id,
                data: {'fkey': StackExchange.options.user.fkey}
            });
            exploit.lastTime = currentTime;
        }
    } else {
        var res = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText)
        exploit.totalNum += res.value;
    }
});
```

You can check how much was mined with `exploit.totalNum`.