# Prevent screen from turning black on server

Tags: server, 14.04, xbmc

I have an Ubuntu server installation with XBMC. After 5 minutes of inactivity the screen turns black and can't be woken up with the remote control. However a keyboard press does wake it up. Since I don't want to use a keyboard this is very annoying.

The black screen doesn't seem to be issued by XBMC itself. It's own screensaver is set to dim after 3 minutes, which it does. XBMC is started using `xinit`.

I'd like to prevent the screen from turning black or find a way to wake it up using the remote.

What I've tried so far is:

- Set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="consoleblank=0"` in `/etc/default/grub` and run `update-grub`.
- Add `BLANK_TIME=0` and `POWERDOWN_TIME=0` in `/etc/kbd/config`

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate of [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/244044/prevent-screen-turning-off-when-watching-video-in-xbmc/)?

Comment: @Aditya No, that's a different problem. Mine doesn't turn of while watching, only after inactivity. Also the solution is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
xset -display :0 s off 
xset -display :0 -dpms 
xset -display :0 s noblank
```

I run this on startup (add it to `/etc/rc.local`) and it works fine. ;)

`:0` of course has to be the display you want to keep from turning black.

Comment: Sounds promising. Did you put this in `/etc/rc.local`? Or does it need to be run by the same user who runs `xinit`?

Comment: Also if `xinit` is run with `-- :0` I guess I have to call `xset -display :0`?